# Modeling one to many relationship using c# and mongodb

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, one-to-many, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a model Ticket and a model Task :

```
public class Ticket
{
   [BsonId] public string _idTicket {get; set;}
   public List<Task> _tasks {get; set;}
}

public class Task
{
   [BsonId] public string _idTask {get; set;}
}
```

How can I model the relationship one to many ? Is it by adding _idTicket in Task Model ?
or there is a method so can mongodb driver do it automatically.

Comment: (It has been a long time I haven't used MongoDb). This model looks like embedded to me, instead of 1-to-many. With 1-to_Many, if I remember right it should be List<MongoDbRef> _tasks (Tasks {get; set;} really, not sure why you only use private fields).

Answer (score 0):

You can just embed the model inside the other model and when this gets serialized it will be a sub-document of the root document. Take the following C# classes for example:

```cs
class Ticket
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Task[] Tasks { get; set; }
}

class Task
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When we insert a few documents into MongoDB using C#

```cs
var client = new MongoClient();
var database = client.GetDatabase("test");
var collection = database.GetCollection<Ticket>("tickets");

await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Ticket
{
    Name = "Ticket-1",
    Tasks = new[]
    {
        new Task{Name = "Task-A"},
        new Task{Name = "Task-B"},
    }
});

await collection.InsertOneAsync(new Ticket
{
    Name = "Ticket-2",
    Tasks = new[]
    {
        new Task{Name = "Task-C"},
        new Task{Name = "Task-D"},
        new Task{Name = "Task-E"},
    }
});
```

We'll see them as the following in the MongoDB console:

```js
db.tickets.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8f4d34602cb605c3f8d72"),
        "Name" : "Ticket-1",
        "Tasks" : [
                {
                        "Name" : "Task-A"
                },
                {
                        "Name" : "Task-B"
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5ed8f4d34602cb605c3f8d73"),
        "Name" : "Ticket-2",
        "Tasks" : [
                {
                        "Name" : "Task-C"
                },
                {
                        "Name" : "Task-D"
                },
                {
                        "Name" : "Task-E"
                }
        ]
}
```

As you can see we don't need a foreign key in the task because it already belongs to the ticket that it's part of.

Comment: Yes, got it, but sometimes we need these embedded documents to be in another collection, how can we manage that ?

Comment: Duplicate what you need in the other instances and keep it up to date with events.